# Maintain Page Layout When Div is Fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 divs that sit below each other. When the middle div scrolls into view it will be fixed for 800 milliseconds then revert back to statically positioned.

During the 800 millisecond period; the middle div is correctly fixed but the last div changes position - instead of staying underneath the middle div it pops up and sits underneath the first div. When the 800 millisecond period is over everything goes back to normal positions.

How can I make the last div maintain its position underneath the middle div whilst the middle div is fixed?

Hope, this makes sense. I've created a JSFiddle to demonstrate the error: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k1h99wc9/6/)

```
<!-- Each div has a height of 900px -->
<div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>

<!-- When this scrolls into view it will become fixed for 800ms. 
     This is when div no. 3 pops up underneath div1 instead of 
     maintaining its position -->
<div id="target">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>

<div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>
```

Comment: why don't you try something like `#target+div{ margin-top:900px; }` for those 800ms

Answer (score 0):

This make sense. your 2nd div is positioned fixed for 800ms. that mes it has no effect on other dives which moves relative to the scrollbar.So your 3rd div comes top ignoring fixed positioned elements.

There are so many solutions as usual. best and easiest way is use invisible div for the same 800ms before 3rd div.just make it display block and height equal to your 2nd div. after 800ms make it display:none;. It will help you to keep 3dr div where you want. your fiddle doesn't work so i cant help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the below css for those 800ms and then revert back to `position:static`

**CSS**

```
#target+div{
margin-top:900px; 
}
```